# On principal ideal domains

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain(PID), $p\in R$ an irreducible element and $k$ a positive integer. Is $R/{Rp^k}$ a finite ring?

Answer (score 1):

No, not in general.  For instance, if $K$ is any field, $R$ could be $K[x]$.  Then $R/Rp^k$ will always be a nontrivial $K$-vector space, so it has at least as many elements as $K$ (and so is infinite if $K$ is infinite).  For a very concrete example, take $p=x$ and $k=1$, and then you get $K[x]/xK[x]\cong K$.